# tabLayout switch delay and views show delay too

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout

I put the frame Layout in a Activity and put numbers of Fragment into frame Layout.

The fragment swith by my custom Drawer menu.

One of the Fragments,it has a tabLayout and four tabs to switch.

So my problem is when i switch back to the fragment,the tab shows dealy.

I try to put the code transaction.addToBackStack(null);  It doesn't work.

Please to teach me how to solve this delay,thanks.

here is my code:

```
@Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    if (id == R.id.homePage) {
            Homepage homepageFragment = new Homepage();
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.replace(R.id.mainFrame, homepageFragment, null);
            setTitleBar(R.string.appTitle);
            transaction.commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.newestInformation) {
            NewsInformation newsFragment = new NewsInformation();
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.replace(R.id.mainFrame, newsFragment, null);
            setTitleBar(R.string.newestInformation);
            transaction.commit();
        }
```

//setContentView

```
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
Homepage homepageFragment = new Homepage();
Fragment fragment = manager.findFragmentById(R.id.mainFrame);
if (fragment == null) {
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.add(R.id.mainFrame, homepageFragment, null);
    setTitleBar(R.string.appTitle);
    transaction.commit();
} else {
    Log.i(TAG, ">>>" + "homepageFragment!=null");
}
```

//xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF">


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/id_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textTitle"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_light" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainFrame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></FrameLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

//the fragment xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/tabLayoutHomePage"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_height="80dp">

    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    <view
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        class="android.support.v4.view.ViewPager"   
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution,because my ViewPager is on nest fragment.
I have to getChildFragmentManager,so i chabge the viewpager code like this:
ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter
                (getChildFragmentManager(), tabLayoutHomePage.getTabCount());